# Tiny volume trades from market-maker

Tags: trading, trading-volume, market-making

I am watching DVAX on Level II. For the past year and a half, I've seen trades executed with normal volume (100, 200, 1500 shares). However, as of the new year, I've started seeing trading done in small random sizes (4, 2, 5 shares). It seems weird that a market-maker would be executing trades like this, unless they were trying to manipulate the stock price. But even if that's the case, what would be the full benefits of trading small orders like this?

[image]

Comment: Those are round lots (100 shares each).

Comment: @BobBaerker Even though they show 5 shares trading?  (the number shown isn't x100).

Comment: Check with your broker.  At every broker that I have been with, Level 2 is quoted in round lots so the '5' would represent 500 shares.  Also, bear in mind that not all trades go through a market maker so don't attribute all of this to him.